# Count folder size + files count of each folder + list down full path (create new file based on count given)

Tags: shell

Team,
I need to have script which will be configurable kind of like it reads properties file to get values and count number of files in each folders (count of file in each folders plus size of that folder)

Ok this listing will be written to file (e.g. configuration limit=10000 then after 10000 line write create new file)

e.g. file1(10000).txt -  contains first list of files 10000
file2.txt - contains second 10000 files list
and so on

**I am able to get file listing and size using below  (but confused how to set configuration limit of 10000 to write?  and count in same??**

```
find <PATH> -name "*.bin" | xargs du -sch
```

Comment: You could pipe the output into `csplit`. I am not 100% certain this will work, but it's worth a try: `find ... | csplit - 10000`.

Comment: Thanks  @berndbausch, but my requirement is like, if I configure let say 1000, after 1000 file it will create new file for next 1000 data. let me try this and get back to you

Comment: That's exactly what `csplit` does when called like that. A new output file every 10000 lines.